# Create UI Components from json response and send data back to server using retrofit

Tags: java, android, android-layout, retrofit2

The is the response, I've to create UI elements in Android, and then send back all the data which is collected from those elements, back to the server. So how it can be done?

```
{
        "widgets":
        [
            {
                "name":"name",
                "type":"inputText",
                "value":"Key Contact Person Name",
                "data":""
            },
            {
                "name":"mobile",
                "type":"inputNumber",
                "value":"Contact person mobile number",
                "data":""
            },
            {
                "name":"alerts",
                "type":"checkbox",
                "value":"Tick if alerts are not required",
                "data":""
            },
            {
                "name":"email",
                "type":"inputEmail",
                "value":"Email ID",
                "data":""
            },
            {
                "name":"estatement",
                "type":"checkbox",
                "value":"Tick if e-statement is not required",
                "data":""
            },
            {
                "name":"physicalStatement",
                "type":"radio",
                "value":Yes,No"",
                "data":""
            },
            {
                "name":"dateOfIncorporation",
                "type":"inputDate",
                "value":"Date of Incorporation",
                "data":""
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: parse the json and check for the key `type` to decide which widget to create and then create the corresponding widget dynamically

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've solved it. Maintained a Hashmap to keep a track of all the object's id, which can later be used to push data to sever. And I've added the elements in the activity, the way you mentioned. Thanks.